# Rule-Based layers not displaying in the correct order

Tags: qgis, polygon, rule-based, order

I am having trouble with bottom layers overlapping upper ones within a rule-based layer. (screen showing the issue) It used to work just fine, I was able to create new polygons under ones previously made, but for some reason, it doesn't work anymore...

I tried to tick and to untick the 'control rendering order', but it doesn't do anything. Is there something I can do/I missed?

[image: Screen of the issue]

Comment: For what you're showing, it seems to me that you are not showing different layers, but just one layer rule-based symbolized. If you place another layer under it, it seems that it is overshadowing. Try either, to place the new layer on top of this one or to set the transparency level so you can see through it (lets say 50%).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clicking *Symbol Levels*.
You can set the order of rendering there AFAIK.

Edit: to elaborate, set *Laves Basaltiques* to have a higher number e.g. **8** than *Mesozoique*, keep at **0**, assuming an order similar to what you have shown.

Simply put QGIS will draw layer 0 first, then 1 on top of that then 2 on top etc...

Answer (score 0):

For what you're showing, it seems to me that you are not showing different layers, but just one layer rule-based symbolized. If you place another layer under it, it seems that it is overshadowing. Try either, to place the new layer on top of this one or to set the transparency level so you can see through it (lets say 50%).